# Writing from an input file to an output file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, file-io, iostream

I'm having troubles opening the my text file in this bit of code. Am I doing it the correct way? Just started C++ this week.

I'm having troubles writing to the output file now. The only output I'm getting is this. libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion
(lldb)

Thanks in advance guys.

Here is my employeesIn.txt

```
<123>,<John>,<Brown>,<125 Prarie Street>,<Staunton>,<IL>,<62088>
<124>,<Matt>,<Larson>,<126 Hudson Road>,<Edwardsville>,<IL>,<62025>
<125>,<Joe>,<Baratta>,<1542 Elizabeth Road>,<Highland>,<IL>,<62088>
<126>,<Kristin>,<Killebrew>,<123 Prewitt Drive>,<Alton>,<IL>,<62026>
<127>,<Tyrone>,<Meyer>,<street>,<999 Orchard Lane>,<Livingston>,<62088>
```

And here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct Person {
string first;
string last;

};

struct Address {
string street;
string city;
string state;
string zipcode;
};

struct Employee {
Person name;
Address homeAddress;
int eid;
};

void readEmployee(istream& in, Employee& e);
void displayEmployee(ostream& out, const Employee& e);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
Employee e[50];

ifstream fin;
ofstream fout;

fin.open("employeesIn.txt");

if (!fin.is_open()) {
    cerr << "Error opening employeesIn.txt for reading." << endl;
    exit(1);
}
fout.open("employeesOut.txt");
if (!fout.is_open()) {
    cerr << "Error opening employeesOut.txt for writing." << endl;
    exit(1);
}
int EmployeePopulation = 0;
readEmployee(fin, e[EmployeePopulation]);
while (!fin.eof()) {
    EmployeePopulation++;
    readEmployee(fin, e[EmployeePopulation]);
}
fin.close();
for (int i = 0; i <= EmployeePopulation - 1; i++) {
    displayEmployee(fout, e[i]);
}

fout.close();

cout << endl;

return 0;
}

void readEmployee(istream& in, Employee& e)
{
string eidText;
if ( getline(in, eidText, ',') ) {
    e.eid = stoi(eidText);

    getline(in, e.name.first, ',');
    getline(in, e.name.last, ',');

    getline(in, e.homeAddress.street, ',');
    getline(in, e.homeAddress.city, ',');
    getline(in, e.homeAddress.state, ',');

    string zipcodeText;
    getline(in, zipcodeText, ',');
    e.homeAddress.zipcode = stoi(zipcodeText);
}


}
void displayEmployee(ostream& out, const Employee& e)
{
out << "Customer Record: " << e.eid
<< endl
<< "Name: " << e.name.first << " " << e.name.last
<< endl
<< "Home address: " << e.homeAddress.street
<< endl
<< e.homeAddress.city << ", " << e.homeAddress.state << " " << e.homeAddress.zipcode
<< endl
<< endl
<< endl;
}
```

Comment: Your error message explains what is wrong. Your program cannot open given file. Check out if file "employeesIn.txt" and your binary file are in the same directory.

Comment: I have it in both folders, so I'm not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: Alright, I figured that out, now the question is why is it not writing it to my employeesOut.txt file? I'm getting no error. Other than this in my output box. libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion
(lldb)

Comment: Use intermediate temp vars, turn all optimization off, do a debug build, use the debugger to breakpoint/step/inspect stuff.  Fix the problems found.

Answer (score 3):

It's precisely what it says: `stoi` failed.

You only have that twice, so it's clear that either your `eidText` is not numeric, or your ZIP code is not numeric.

We don't know whether this is due to a problem with your input file or a problem with your parsing, so output `eidText` and `zipcodeText` to the console before you `stoi` them, so you can see what their values are, then continue your diagnosis accordingly.

Comment: I've changed my original post to include what my employeesIn.txt file looks like. Do I need to change my zipcode declaration from string zipcode; to int zipcode; ?

Comment: So just change anywhere it says fout, to cout so I can see the values in the console?

Comment: @MatthewTingle No.... Which book are you using? Now that you've added your input, it's clear what's going on. You read the text `"<62025>"` into `zipcodeText` and then use `std::stoi` to convert it to an integer. But `<62025>` is not an integer. You need to handle those `<`/`>` somehow. Simply writing `zipcodeText` to console using a temporary line of code would have revealed this to you, trivially!

Comment: So to output zipcodeText to the console, so I can see it. I simply write << cout zipcodeText; before my main correct?

Comment: C++ Programming, Program Design Including Data Structures by D.S. Malik Sixth Edition

Comment: A C++ book should teach you how to write to console, and where to write imperative statements. Here's [some good ones](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/560648).

Comment: A book on general debugging/troubleshooting techniques my be even better.